# Find load average of server using ssh in php

Tags: php, ssh

I want to find the load average of the server to which am connected full time, I used the following code, but I get error on displaying the up time. please some one help me fix this...

Here is the code

```
<?php
$ip = '192.168.71.56';
$user = 'viju';
$pass = 'viju';
$connection = ssh2_connect($ip);
if($connection)
{  
 echo "connection successful";
}
else
{
 echo "connection failed";
}

if(!(ssh2_auth_password($connection,$user,$pass)))
{
  echo "Authentication Failed"; 
}
else
{
 echo "Authentication Successful";
 $shell = ssh2_exec($connection,"uptime");   
 if($shell)
 {
  $loadAvgString=explode('average:',$shell);   //error occurs here
  print_r($loadAvgString);
  $loadAvgInAnArray=explode(',',$loadAvgString);
  print_r($loadAvgInAnArray);
 }
 else
 { 
  echo "No data fetched";
 }
}
?>
```

I get the following output with Warning

connection successful Authentication Successful Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, resource given in /var/www/extra/dis.php on line 26 Array ( [0] => )

Comment: what's the difference between `system` and `server` ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to combine your php knowledge with Linux-fu to make this happen.
One way to get the load average is with the 'uptime' command on the command line.
[Here is a nice example of uptime's output](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/get-cpu-system-load-average-on-ubuntu-linux/).

To use it on the remote system via ssh.. You can base it off [this example here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-exec.php)

Then you just need to parse the output of output of uptime.
Here is an example:

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('shell.example.com', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');

$response= ssh2_exec($connection, 'uptime');
//if you are new, regex is hard... so you can use explode to parse the string
$loadAvgString=explode('average:',$response);
//this array will contain your load avg amounts. you still need to trim() the whitespace
$loadAvgInAnArray=explode(',',$loadAvgString);
```